# Autoincrement field is not being automatically set

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I'm having error with the column Id cannot contain null values but i set to true on IsDbGenerated.  what am i doing wrong?

```
private int id;
[Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, CanBeNull=false, DbType="int", IsDbGenerated=true)]
public int Id
{
    get { return id; }
    set
    {
        if (id != value)
        {
            id = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about in database. have you set idetity=yes in database

Comment: it is sdf (SQLce) for Windows Phone in Isolated storage.

Comment: http://www.any-ti.me/manually-setting-autoincrement-identity-fields-in-sqlce-31-and-35.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private int id;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true, DbType="INT NOT NULL IDENTITY", CanBeNull=false, AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set 
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                id = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }
```